# Database desing suggestion

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was designing a database, here's a context of how it looks:

> I have an application.
>
> Application will have appliant.
>
> Applicant(Application) may or may not have a co-applicant.
>
> Applicant has infos like : Demographic, General Info, Employment Info, Reference etc...
>
> If co-applicant exists it will have the same infos: Demographic, General Info, Employment Info, Reference etc...

*My proposed design looks something like this:*

```
 Table: application [pk: applicaion_id]

 Table: applicant   [pk: applicant_id, fk: applicaiton_id {references: application.applicaion_id} ]

 Table: co_applicant [pk: ( applicant_id {references: applicant.applicant_id},  co_applicants_applicant_id {references: applicant.applicant_id} ) ]

 Table demographic [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]

 Table employment [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]
```

etc...

applicant table holds general info about applicant, similary co-applicant holds general info about co-applicant

Here's an *alternative to the design,*

```
 Table: application  [pk: applicaion_id]

 Table: applicant    [pk: applicant_id, fk: applicaiton_id {references: application.applicaion_id} ]

 Table: co_applicant [pk: co_applicant_id, fk: applicaiton_id {references: application.applicaion_id} ]

 Table demographic   [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]

 Table employment    [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]

 Table co_applicant_demographic   [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]

 Table co_applicant_employment    [pk: demographic_id, fk: appicant_id{references: applicant.applicant_id} ]
```

table for each of the co_applicant's info.

Which of the design would you suggest or any better alternative would be very helpful along with its advantage and disadvantage.

> Edit: Read-Queries could be pretty heavy and search queries can be intense as well.

Comment: what kind of queries is your application going to make? eg. search queries, read-heavy or write-heavy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're duplicating a lot of stuff between "applicant" and "co_applicant", especially the duplicate tables. Crazy.

Treat them all as "applicants" and have just one `applicant` table, but have two FKs in the `application` table back to it - `applicant_id` and `co_applicant_id`